# stray style from css causing image fragment duplication

Tags: css

On my website I've got a style (class="more") that is overrunning its bounds and doing something strange. I'm not enough of a css guru to know how to fix this. Please take a look:

http://www.zerogravpro.com/

Now look at my screenshot describing the problem:

https://www.chainedpayments.com/temp/zgp.png

How can I fix this? Additionally I really like that little "more" snippet of image and css, and would love to be able to use it in more places. But the css is really awkward and when I try to use class="more" in other places, it doesn't look right. In fact just using it in the 1 place on my home page is causing the problem shown in the screenshot.

I'd really appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it so all `<p>` tags inside `#bodyPanel` have that image as their background.

Correct way to do it:

HTML

```
<p class="man_bg">Blah Blah blah</p>
```

CSS

```
#bodyPanel p {
    margin: 0 0 0 54px;
    padding: 0 42px 35px 150px;
    color: #0F0F0F;
}
#bodyPanel p.man_bg {
    background: url(images/papersandsky.png) 0 0 no-repeat white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...you got me halfway there. But I still have a large awkward gap right below the word Testimonials. Please see screenshot with IE Developer Toolbar open: http://www.chainedpayments.com/temp/zgp2.jpg      - it seems the "more" class is still causing problems. How can I close that gap, and also be able to use the "more" image/css further down inside my testimonials where I just have the "more" link. I tried applying that class and it doesn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
#bodyPanel p{background:url(images/papersandsky.png) 0 0 no-repeat #fff; margin:0 0 0 54px; padding:0 42px 35px 150px; color:#0F0F0F;}
```

You have that background set to apply to all p tags within anything containing the id of `#bodyPanel`

You need to probably be more specific with your selectors and add a class to any p tag where you want the background.

Comment: Please see comment I left above...I'd love to hear your ideas as well.